# Angular2 + webpack do not deploy robots.txt

Tags: angular, webpack, robots.txt

I am creating a web site with Angular2@2.1.2.
I am using Webpack with default settings (as a dependency).

Here is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
"@angular/core": "2.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "2.1.2",
"@angular/http": "2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.1.2",
"@angular/router": "3.1.2",
"@ngrx/core": "1.2.0",
"@ngrx/effects": "2.0.0",
"@ngrx/store": "2.2.1",
"angular2-toaster": "^1.0.1",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "2.2.1",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"bootstrap-select": "1.11.2",
"eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "4.17.42",
"es5-shim": "4.5.9",
"intl": "1.2.5",
"jquery": "3.1.0",
"moment": "2.15.1",
"ng2-modal": "0.0.21",
"ng2-pagination": "^0.4.1",
"ngrx-store-logger": "^0.1.7",
"npm": "3.9.3",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
"zone.js": "0.6.25"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/jasmine": "2.2.34",
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
"codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
"core-js": "2.4.1",
"jasmine-core": "2.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.7.0",
"karma": "1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
"karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
"karma-verbose-reporter": "0.0.3",
"node-sass": "3.10.3",
"protractor": "4.0.5",
"ts-node": "1.3.0",
"tslint": "3.15.1",
"typescript": "2.0.2"
}
```

I have added a **robots.txt** file in the **assets/** directory. I was thinking that the builder (npm build) recognizes this file and put it at the root of the application, but it does not, it is still in the assets directory.

Do I miss something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I have found my solution in this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1942

robots.txt is in src/ directory
Modify angular-cli.json

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": ["assets", "robots.txt"],
 ....
```

Use the assets array to declare files you want to be placed in the root of dist/

Answer (score 22):

I made this work with Angular6.

Place your robots.txt in the src folder, the same folder as the favicon.ico.

In your angular.json file

```js
              "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/robots.txt"
            ],
```

You may need to ng serve again, then point to http://localhost:4200/robots.txt

Comment: If I am caching all unknown routes (path:'**') what can I do? should I add a route for the robots.txt?

Comment: I just tried to one of my applications and seems to be working on angular 10.1.1 using angular universal server side rendering. it hasn't problems with (path:'**'), I recommend update your answer removing the "This will only work if you are not catching all unknown routes (path:'**') in your router module(s). " sentence.

Comment: this did not work for me, instead glob worked as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902703/ignore-a-path-in-the-root-routermodule

Answer (score 1):

I wanted my `robots.txt` to be in my `src/assets` folder rather than just `src`. I found that the following being added to my `angular.json` in the `assets` array did the trick:

```json
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "robots.txt",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "./"
  }
],
```

Works in Angular 10 using Angular Universal/SSR.