# Using Angular 2, how can I allow robots.txt to be viewed without angular routing being triggered?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, robots.txt

I'm using Angular 2 and just added a robots.txt to the root of my dist folder on production (for SEO purposes)

But the file isn't accessible since the url `https://myrandomsite.com/robots.txt` just redirects to my PageNotFoundComponent because of how my routing is setup.

How can I allow robots.txt to be accessed "normally" and prevent my Angular 2 routing config to trigger?

**Edit:** I am using Angular2 frontend with a Firebase backend.

Comment: Add meta tag...

Comment: @Jai care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

That's no Angular problem, its one of your webserver.

Your webserver shouldn't redirect an URL to an existing file back to `/index.html`.

See this IIS example configuration for redirecting with rules:

```xml
    <rule name="AngularJS" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
    </rule>
```

IIS won't redirect if its a file, directory or URL starts with `/api`!

**UPDATE**

Using firebase you should read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites

Comment: Ok, I have no idea how IIS works. I am using Firebase so I don't have access o a web server. I will update my post with this info.

Comment: Was just a hint where's the problem, shouldnt be a solution! :) See my updated answer..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628306/angular2-webpack-do-not-deploy-robots-txt

Comment: Though there should be an entry in angular.json for the angular routing to be ignored. just like the way for /assets & images